# How can I call an event from another class?

Tags: wxpython

I have two classes like this:

```
class ClassNrOne(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Title',size=(1024,600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,size=(1024,600))
        self.mybutton = wx.Button(self.panel,label="OK",pos=(215,160),size=(80,40))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, ClassNrTwo.do, self.mybutton)

class ClassNrTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,id)
        self.newpanel = wx.Panel(self,size=(1024,600))
    def do(self,event):
        # do something
```

When I try to run this, I get the error message: "'ClassNrOne' object has no attribute 'ClassNrTwo'". If I try it backwards -> self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, do.ClassNrTwo, self.mybutton) I get the message: "global name 'do' is not defined". How can I call an event from another class?

2nd Question regarding to this: Is it also possible to call the '__init__' from ClassNrTwo when 'mybutton' is clicked?

Edit:
I just combined all my little questions to one big question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604139/need-tutorial-for-menubar-handling-panel-building

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? and what are you trying to do here? if you really need to call some function from other class, you can make instance of `ClassNrTwo` then in `ClassNrOne` you can do something like this.

```
classnrtwo = ClassNrTwo(self, wx.ID_ANY)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, classnrtwo.do, self.mybutton)
```

But, personally I do not recommend to use it like that, and it's not call an event from other class, it simply just using other class functions.

For second question, `__init__` is magic function (good explanation [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)) act like a constructor it will automatically called when you create an instance of the class, like example above, `__init__` function of `ClassNrTwo' will automatically run too.

Hope this help,

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems like I have to think about my whole program... I just started learning python (learning by doing). One of the most important thing in my program is, that I have a lot of menubar-entries and each entry shall show an other panel BUT these panels shouldn't be static: everytime I open one of these panel it shall be rebuilded / updated. (e.g. when I change the value in a wx.Choice in menubar-entry#1 then a wx.staticText in menubar-entry#2 shall change)... But maybe I should add a new question for this =)

Comment: I just combined all my little questions to one big question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604139/need-tutorial-for-menubar-handling-panel-building